# install some software "natively" on a computer?

Tags: word-choice

Windows can be installed on a computer directly, or installed inside a virtual box under Linux.

Is it correct to say the former case to be

> Windows is installed **natively** on a computer?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Most dictionaries have a _computing_ definition of native, and there's also a wikipedia entry, which you should see for further info. (As an aside: _Is it correct to say the former case to be_ is not grammatical. Perhaps _is it correct to say in the former case that_ or something similar is what you were looking for.)

Comment: I'd say it depends on your target audience - anyone who understands what 'natively' implies will understand "Windows is [or I'd prefer 'can be'] installed natively on a computer" Anyone who doesn't understand 'natively' will be better helped by your original version.

Comment: Note it may be to counter "non-native" options like webapps (e.g. Google Docs), which technically run on the computer but are both loaded and heavily dependent on remote services. The line may be blurred at times.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In computing, software is said to run "natively" on a platform if it is running without modification or the help of an intermediary software layer.

**Examples:**

Windows runs natively on most home PCs.
Microsoft Word runs natively on Windows.
Apple's Keynote runs natively on MacOS.
An old video game played in an arcade emulator is **not** running natively.

Keep in mind that the meaning is dependent on context. Consider Microsoft Word running on Windows, which is in turn running in VirtualBox (a hardware virtualization program) on a Mac. In this case, Word is running natively on Windows, but it is *not* running natively on the Mac. Windows is *not* running natively on the computer, but VirtualBox *is* running natively on MacOS.

As some other comments have suggested, you might want to use alternative ways of describing the setup if there is a possibility of confusing your audience with this term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that "natively" conveys the technically accurate term here. If you say Windows is natively installed, i consider that to mean it was the original operating system. If it was installed as a secondary OS, i might just use "Windows was installed directly on the computer."